# Firebase, Store data

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to capture the end of an event on Firebase? for example: writing data.
What I'd like to do is to use an event on Firebase which can let know that all the data (send manually) has been store on Firebase.

Comment: If you look in the documentation on updating documents, you'll see a way to detect when the write have completed on the server: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Comment: I would like to ask, what do you mean by "all the data"?